# Use percentage to work out location based on screen resoultion in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, logic

I have two items on a WPF I would like to calculate the start y and end y based on the screen resoultion and percentage. I have the following items

Text

Button

I would like to obtain the text Y which is fine

Text X / Y position on all res

```
1600 x 900 = x=348 y=72
1920 x 1200 = x= 348 y=72
1600 x 1200 = x=348 y=72
1400 x 1050 = x= 348 y= 72
```

I would like to write something in c# to give me a start Y and end y of the button based on the resoultion

Button y and w/h

```
1600 x 900 = y-221, w=319, h=50
1920 x 1200 = y-248, w= 303, h =50
1600 x 1200 = y-248, w=319, h=50
1400 x 1050 = y-271, w=319, h=50
```

Currently I have these hardcoded but would like to calculate by percentage

select item where the following condition is true with a case statement for the screen resoultions

```
x()>={0} and x()<={1} and y()>={2} and y()<={3}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Point locationFromScreen = myButton.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));
        PresentationSource source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this);
        Point targetPoints = source.CompositionTarget.TransformFromDevice.Transform(locationFromScreen);
        Console.WriteLine("Top Y Coord: " + targetPoints.Y);
        Console.WriteLine("Bottom Y Coord: " + (targetPoints.Y + myButton.ActualHeight));
        Console.WriteLine("Left X Coord: " + targetPoints.X);
        Console.WriteLine("Right X Coord: " + (targetPoints.X + myButton.ActualWidth));
```

Comment: Let me explain a bit more. so i'm using Ranorex with c# To automate testing.